# I need to match the list of elements with the following pattern

Tags: python, regex

Pattern: `arl$en`

starts with `arl`
ends with `en`

`$` can be any word `{"a" - "z", "0123456789", ". , ! ? :"}`

Valid examples:

```
arlen
arl!?en
arlwerwen
arlren
arl.en
arl?en
arl0123.en
arl1en
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You may use: `r'^arl[a-z0-9,.!?:]*en$'` in python.

Comment: try https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that checks the conditions one after another like the code below. It checks if string starts and ends with the patterns you wanted and if that was true it checks if all the chars in between are an element of the set of chars you define.
Code:

```
def checkstring(s):
    if not (s.startswith("arl") and s.endswith("en")):
        return False
    for i in s[3:-2]:
        if not i in "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,?!:":
            return False
    return True
```